# Select multiple Rows without pressing Control Key

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, selection

I have a gridview where I can select multiple rows by pressing a control key. Is it possible to achieve the same without pressing a control key.

Comment: If you select multiple rows without control key how will you deselect them?

Comment: @Giorgi by clicking a row again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the .net default action will also update the `slectedrows` of your `datagridview` you need to have an array to reserve the old selections:

```
DataGridViewRow[] old;
```

which will be updated at `CellMouseDown` (before the default .net action modify your selections):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    old = new DataGridViewRow[dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count];
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows.CopyTo(old,0);  
}
```

after that, you can do your changes in `RowHeaderMouseClick` (as `RowHeaderSelect` is the default datagridview `selectionmode`) or use `CellMouseClick` for `FullRowSelect` and reselect those old selected rows:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{    
    foreach (DataGridViewRow gr in old)
    {
        if (gr == dataGridView1.CurrentRow)
        {
            gr.Selected = false;
        }
        else
        {
            gr.Selected = true;
        }    
    }  
}
```

**Edit: Better solution:**
You need to implement your own `datagridview` derived from the original one and override `OnCellMouseDown`&`OnCellMouseClick` to cancel the default deselect action and make it smooth. make a new Class as something like this:

```
Using System;
Using System.Windows.Forms;

public class myDataGridView:DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnCellMouseDown(e);
        this.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = !this.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected;
    }

    protected override void OnCellMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnCellMouseClick(e);
    }
}
```

and in your Form.Designer.cs change `DataGridView` object `datagridview1` (if that is the name) to `myDataGridView` object......

For example:Change

`private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;` to

```
private myDataGridView dataGridView1;
```

and change

`this.dataGridView1=new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()` to

```
this.dataGridView1=new myDataGridView ()
```

Comment: but i am using FullRowSelect selection mode.I can't find FullRowSelectMouseClick event.

Comment: I have tested u'r code but its look like that gird refreshed every time i select any row.

Comment: @Gulshan, it's refreshing because it was doing deselect and reselect.  I think my answer already gives you the right solution for your question above, and from my answer you should have enough knowledge of what to do next even without my comments above, as I'm just trying to help and not supposed to do the work for you.....

Comment: @Gulshan, have you tested my solution above? since no more comments from you after my update.

Comment: This myDataGridView:DataGridView trick not only allows one to select multiple cells without holding down ctrl, it also allows you to click on one of the selected cells and start to drag it without deselecting it.  Neat solution!

Comment: I implemented custom grid as described in your answer, it worked perfectly, but i did not have to declare an array to save old selection, did you put two solutions in your answer, if yes, then please divided your answer with an OR so there is no confusion.

Comment: @alphaprolix, many thanks for the feedback, I've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this for a touch screen where I wanted multiselect on single click, without ugly check boxes.
Why over complicate it, just keep a not of the Index'es

```
    private List<int> SelectedIndexs { get; set; }
```

Then add or remove them from the list as you click them...
Then look through you datagrid and select the rows in the list.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedIndexs.Contains(e.RowIndex))
        {
            SelectedIndexs.Remove(e.RowIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedIndexs.Add(e.RowIndex);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Selected = SelectedIndexs.Contains(row.Index);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way out can be putting a checkbox in each row and possibly a "select all" checkbox on the header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to mouse click event and select the row programmatically by setting [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.selected.aspx) property to true.

Keep in mind that ff the row is already selected you need to set it to false so that the user is able to deselect the row.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it, but it should be possible to use the MouseDown and MouseUp events to select any rows that are under the cursor when you move the mouse while holding one of the buttons down.

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply is a bit late but for everyone..

you can use InputSimulator and do this:

```
InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();


    private void CommandeDataGridView_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.LCONTROL);
    }

    private void CommandeDataGridView_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sim.Keyboard.KeyUp(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.LCONTROL);
    }
```