# Emulating the ListBox's MultiSimple SelectionMode for DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I've set the SelectionMode for my DGV to FullRowSelect and MultiSelect to true.

Because this is going to be used on a touch screen where the user may not have access to a keyboard to hold the control or shift buttons down while selecting items, I would like to emulate the behavior that the ListBox uses with its MultiSimple mode.

I'm wondering what the easiest way to do this might be.  My first thought was to capture the mouse down event and then 'press' the control key for the user, but I'm actually not sure how I would do that though.  I know how to use SendKeys, but I'm thinking that would just press & release the control key rather than giving me the ability to choose when the button is released.

Suggestions?

EDIT: I have tried the solution listed here: [Select multiple Rows without pressing Control Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915745/select-multiple-rows-without-pressing-control-key)

The problem with this solution is that it looks horrible when the screen flickers every time you change the selection.  I would like something that doesn't give potential customers a bad impression of the product.

The way I see it, the only way to do this is either to be able to simulate holding the control button down when the user clicks, or else to prevent the datagrid from deselecting other rows when the user clicks.  Suggestions on how to do either of these things would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would override the original `DataGridView` class and change the `OnCellMouseDown` event.

Code as follows:

```
public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public MyDataGridView()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = !this.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected;
    }
}
```

I tried it on my machine with `DataGridView` containing more than 1000 rows and it works pretty well (no flickering).
The problem with this approach is the case where your `DataGridView` cells are editable. But I don't see a reason to combine `MultiSelect` along with editable cells, it just make no sense.

Comment: Thanks... I don't guess there's a way to do this without having to extend the DGV class though? Would almost rather use some clunky reflection if possible so the logic can be applied to existing DGVs without having to replace them (although I guess reflection can't really help you override a method).  But this will definitely work if necessary.

Comment: I ended up trying a low level mouse hook with some other code I found to press/release the control key for a few milliseconds.  It seems to work well right now, although I have a sneaking suspicion I'll end up running into problems with it before it's all said and done.  I'll give it a week and either mark yours the answer if I come back to this solution or post mine if it looks like it's gonna continue to work without side-effects.