# How to multiselect DataGridView rows without pressing CTRL key in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to c# and using windows forms.

I have a DataGridView control on a form and I need to allow a user to multi-select rows without pressing the CTRL key and without using check box column. I have already enabled the mutli-select property.

I know this is duplicated question on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915745/select-multiple-rows-without-pressing-control-key) but I tried the first answer (Bolu answer) and it worked but the datagridvied refreshes and flicks every time I select a row.

I wanted to try the "Edit: Better solution" (in the same answer) and it is too complicated for me I did not understand the steps.

My question: How can I get rid of the flicking/ refreshing process and make it smooth when I select a row? (the code shown below), also I am happy to receive any new solutions. Please help me, thank you

```
DataGridViewRow[] old;
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    old = new DataGridViewRow[dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count];
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows.CopyTo(old, 0);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow gr in old)
    {
        if (gr == dataGridView1.CurrentRow)
        {
            gr.Selected = false;
        }
        else
        {
            gr.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be very well worth to study the 'better solution' . What it does is to create a __subclass__  `myDataGridView` of `DataGridView` the has the wanted behaviour. All you need to do is to add a new  class to __either__ your project of even just to your form; the code is the new class in the post. To test you can add the class into your form, __right before the very last__ curly brace at the very bottom of the `form.cs` file. Then compile! now you can either..

Comment: ..: add a new obejct of the new subclass by dragging it from the toolbox (where is appears at the very top) or you can follow the steps in the post by changing the type of the dgv(s) you already have to the new type  `myDataGridView` ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this; keep the `datagridview` (`dgvTopics` in my case) mutiselect `true`:

```
private void dgvTopics_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvTopics.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected == true)
        dgvTopics.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "U";
    else
        dgvTopics.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "S";  
}

private void dgvTopics_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dgvTopics.Rows)
    {
        if(dgvr.ErrorText == "S")
            dgvr.Selected = true;
        else
            dgvr.Selected = false;
    }
}
```